# Coloring in VS Code - precedence of rules

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the explorer of VS Code I want to have the gitignored files grey.

I managed to add `"gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground":"#CCCCCC"`, however I now have various files and folders where there are other decorations and it looks like `explorer.decorations.colors` takes precedence over this. This mechanism now destroys the coloring of the ignored resources again as it looks like this rule is checked later.

How can I fix this and have the gitignored rule applied no matter what happens otherwise?

This is for:

**VSCode:** Version: 1.73.1
Release: 22314
Commit: 14f2d26367b7e8f03ff2352516ba27d6302dd7b1
Date: 2022-11-10T18:37:51.314Z (2 wks ago)
Electron: 19.0.17
Chromium: 102.0.5005.167
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.15-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 19.6.0
Sandboxed: No

**MacOS:** Catalina 10.15.7

**Git:** 2.38.1

[image: Screenshot]

The screenshot shows a situation where `chamaeleon/` is part of `.gitignore`. All files nicely are greyed out with the exception of `ChameleonTemplate.php` which contains a PHP error, as well as `src`which contains a file containing an error and `Components` which contains another file with an editor decoration due to a type problem in PHP.

**Clarification:** My question is not about files which are *only* gitignored (they show uo correctly) but about files which are gitognored **and** have a further editor decoration (such as a syntax error). If these two decorations apply *both* then the question is *which one takes precedence*. **That** is the problem here.

My question is rather not a bug (as in "does not work as expected") but a conceptual one. If we have two different reasons for setting foreground color, and both reasons apply, which color is chosen?

A workaround would be if we were able to set other attributes such as underline, strike-through, background-color or font type and not only foreground-color, because such attributes could be combined. Foreground-color and foreground-color cannot be combined but needs a precedence rule.

Comment: any chnce to screenshot to better clarify your question? also, seems that `gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground` config is dependent on some extension - mid to clarify which one it belongs to?

Comment: Added screenshot.

Comment: The question is not related to programming. Please migrate it to superuser.

Comment: @kometen How would I migrate? Particularly with all the activity we had here already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should provide more information, like VS Code and git version. I am running VS Code 1.73.1 and git 2.37.1 in macOS and it works automatically.

Possible solutions:

- It could just be a bug in VS Code or git. Check if you are running the latest versions.
- Restart VS Code.
- Try to clone the project again.
- Check that your project is not a symlinked folder.

Comment: Checked all of your 4 suggestions, none solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see now, what your problem is. I don't know the answer for overriding gitDecorations over explorerDecorations. As far as my knowledge goes for now, I think it can't be done.

Comment: Krivic: I would even go further: It is a conceptual design error to have two attributes that could apply at the same time visualized in the UI with UI attributes that cannot be applied at the same time (as with foreground color).

Comment: Probably the **core** is in the remark "I think it can't be done". Which is why I award the bounty here for this user.

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened automatically... I think you just need the **high-contrast dark** color theme in vscoode. You could also choose another color theme but this changes. You could also look into making you own color theme for vscode like I did, and edit the colors to your liking.
[image: My VSCODE]

As you can see, `fort-bishop.exe` is grayed out. I have ignored it in my `.gitignore`.

Comment: Files which are only gitgnored in my case show up correctly. The problem is with files where not only the gitignore applies but there also is an editor annotation. You example does not apply here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you missed `workbench.colorCustomizations`.
In your `settings.json`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "gitDecoration.ignoredResourceForeground": "#ff0000"
}
```

Comment: My toplevel JSON reads exactly like this. Moreover, as I write in the question: I see the effect of the gitDecoration. There just is an override for those files which have another warning from the editor. So, probably this does not apply here.

Comment: I also have "workbench.colorTheme": "GitHub Dark". Probably colorCustomizations only work, if colorTheme defines one.

Comment: "explorer.decorations.colors" is true for me, though I can override the color with  colorCustomizations

Comment: Is your "explorer.decorations.colors" also set to true?

Comment: `explorer.decorations.colors` is set to true. Changing it to false has the expected effect. Probably not related to this. In general, colorCustomizations work for me. Only in this **specific** situation they do not work. I updated the question to make this more precise.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like a [known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/70963). Yet, please add VSCode version details. Below are the possible workarounds which might help:

1. Clear the git cache, re-add the files and re-commit. Re-save the .gitignore files once again.
2. Make a dummy edit to the .gitignore file and try saving the file.

Comment: Followed the two suggestions. Everything works as expected. The problem only remains for files which are gitignore-colored and decoration-colored.